# Accessing html elements which do not have tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to iterate through html with beautifulsoup, but it looks that I can not reach all elements. Here is orignal link (http://china-market-research.blogspot.com/2018/10/why-kid-market-is-booming-in-china.html)

I have html like this:

```
<div class="post-body entry-content" id="post-body-2820943256231169701" itemprop="description articleBody">
Why Kid Market is Booming in China  ?<br>
<br>
Very simple , look at this video you will get it.<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<iframe allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="573" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fg7jIjmLyWs" width="1019"></iframe>

<br>
<br>
<br>
&nbsp;Birth control: a rule, not a pill
China’s two-child policy is having unintended consequences
Reluctant to pay for multiple maternity leaves, companies are choosing not to hire young women

<br>
THE one-child-per-couple policy was horrific for women in China. Many were subjected to forced sterilisations or abortions. Newborn girls were killed, removed by family-planning officials or abandoned by parents desperate that their one permitted baby be a boy. Women from neighbouring countries suffered, too, as victims of human trafficking; a skewed sex-ratio made it more difficult for young men to find Chinese wives. So the government’s announcement in late 2015 that it was relaxing the policy, after 35 years, was good news. Yet the two-child-per-couple policy that replaced it may bring different kinds of problems. source&nbsp;<a href="https://www.economist.com/china/2018/07/26/chinas-two-child-policy-is-having-unintended-consequences">https://www.economist.com/china/2018/07/26/chinas-two-child-policy-is-having-unintended-consequences</a><br>
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
For a generation the government assured women that “one is enough” and that “late marriage and late childbirth are worthy.” Now state media urge them to marry while still in university and remind them that older mothers are more likely to have babies with birth defects, notes Leta Hong Fincher, an author and academic. Officials are encouraging childbirth because they worry that the fertility rate (the number of children a woman can expect to have during her lifetime) has sunk well below 2.1, the level required to keep the population stable in the long term. They fear a shrinking population will hamper economic growth.</blockquote>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to reach each element including those which do not have any tag and are just plain text. So when I am interating I should see 
this element also "China’s two-child policy is having unintended consequences
Reluctant to pay for multiple maternity leaves, companies are choosing not to hire young women".
Thats my code:

```
article_soup = BeautifulSoup(article_html, "html.parser")
find_entry_content = article_soup.find('div',class_="post-body entry-content")
for first_parent_tag in find_entry_content.find_all():
            print(first_parent_tag)
```

And here is the result from code above:

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<iframe allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="573" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fg7jIjmLyWs" width="1019"></iframe>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="https://www.economist.com/china/2018/07/26/chinas-two-child-policy-is-having-unintended-consequences">https://www.economist.com/china/2018/07/26/chinas-two-child-policy-is-having-unintended-consequences</a>
<br/>
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
For a generation the government assured women that “one is enough” and that “late marriage and late childbirth are worthy.” Now state media urge them to marry while still in university and remind them that older mothers are more likely to have babies with birth defects, notes Leta Hong Fincher, an author and academic. Officials are encouraging childbirth because they worry that the fertility rate (the number of children a woman can expect to have during her lifetime) has sunk well below 2.1, the level required to keep the population stable in the long term. They fear a shrinking population will hamper economic growth.</blockquote>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share what it does find? You should be able to find the raw text in the main div.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock I updated the question with result and original link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find_all() loops over all the tags/children in the div. While the text you are looking for is in the div, it's not under a tag/child tags.

```
<div>
"Some text" # <----- This will be skipped because it isn't a HTML (child) tag in the Div. It's right in the div
"Some more text" # <----- This will also be skipped for the same reason.
<br/>
<iframe allow= .... >
<br/>
<br/>
<a href ....>
<br/>
<blockquote class="tr_bq">
For a generation the government assured women that .... </blockquote>
# ^ This text is found because it's in a blockquote ,which find_all() is looping over'
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

So instead of looping over all the tags in the div, also look in the div itself. It should contain all the elements that are not in children of the div.

Comment: Thank you, I removed find_all and eveything works fine now.